# Why can't get any WM_MOUSEMOVE message when calling SetCapture for a ListBox control?

Tags: windows

**FIRST OF ALL**

I am not a native English speaker. There may be a lot of grammar mistakes in the sentences. I will try as I can to express the result I am trying to achieve and the problems I am experancing. It blocked me for some while,depressed me. I really need some help for pointing where I was wrong and what I should do. Thank you for your attention.

**WHAT I AM DOING**

I am trying to redraw the win32 standard control WC_LISTBOX. According MSDN, you can change the background color , the text font , text color , border size, do your owner drawing of each listbox items. The interface of the WC_LISTBOX control provided by microsoft works very well except the inner-builted scrollbar .

The default scrollbar of this control is some white or gray piece, two arrows, a scrolling chanel, a thumb block.

I want to do my own painting for the scrollbar of the control. I chosed the dark color for the control. The font color, background color, text color and so on as above referred can be adjusted by the interface provided. But for the scrollbar, there is barely no interface. The only choice seems to rewrite the NCPaint.

After a lot of searching and test codings,several messsages need to handle by myself. What I am doing in my mind is : If user click left mouse button on the thumb rect of the scrollbar, it trigged the dragging action. When user dragging the thumb zone, I capture the mousemove message , and update the scrollinfo the scrollbar, and paint the scrollbar according the scrollinfo updated.

1. `WM_NCCALCSIZE`: I need to calcalate and set the zone of the Non-client and client rect.

```
int ListBox_NCCalcSize(HWND hwnd,LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS calc)
{
    RECT rect_new;
    RECT rect_old;
    RECT client_rect_new;
    RECT client_rect_old;
    pLBStyle ls=ListBox_GetSettings(hwnd);
    BOOL IsVScroll=(((UINT)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE)&WS_VSCROLL)==WS_VSCROLL);

    CopyRect(&rect_new,&(calc->rgrc[0]));
    CopyRect(&rect_old,&(calc->rgrc[1]));
    CopyRect(&client_rect_old,&(calc->rgrc[2]));
    
    //set new rect for listbox control.
    client_rect_new = {rect_new.left+ls->margin_border,
                       rect_new.top+ls->margin_border,
                       rect_new.right-ls->margin_border-(IsVScroll?SCROLLBAR_PIXLS:0),
                       rect_new.bottom-ls->margin_border};
    CopyRect(&(calc->rgrc[0]),&client_rect_new);
    CopyRect(&(calc->rgrc[1]),&rect_new);
    CopyRect(&(calc->rgrc[2]),&rect_old);
    
    return WVR_VALIDRECTS;
}
```

2. `WM_NCACTIVATE`/`WM_NCPAINT`: Repaint the border and the scrollbar of the control.

```
int ListBox_NCPaint(HWND hwnd)
{
    pLBStyle ls=ListBox_GetSettings(hwnd);
    
    if(!ls) return -1;
    
    HDC hdc=GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    UINT style=GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd,GWL_STYLE);
    RECT rc={0},rc_mem;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd,&rc);
    CopyRect(&rc_mem,&rc);
    OffsetRect(&rc_mem,-rc_mem.left,-rc_mem.top);
    
    //memory device context
    HDC memdc=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bmp=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,rc_mem.right,rc_mem.bottom);
    HBITMAP pre_bmp=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc,bmp);
    
    //reflesh the background
    COLORREF color_trans=RGB(0,0,1);
    HBRUSH brush=CreateSolidBrush(color_trans);
    FillRect(memdc,&rc_mem,brush);
    
    //border
    if((style&WS_BORDER)==WS_BORDER) {
        RECT rc_tmp;
        CopyRect(&rc_tmp,&rc_mem);
        for(int index=0;index<ls->margin_border;index++) {
            FrameRect(memdc,&rc_tmp,ls->brush_border);
            InflateRect(&rc_tmp,-1,-1);
        }
    }
    
    //Blt
    TransparentBlt(hdc,0,0,(rc.right-rc.left),(rc.bottom-rc.top),
                   memdc,0,0,rc_mem.right,rc_mem.bottom,color_trans);
    
    DeleteObject(brush);
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(memdc,pre_bmp));
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int ListBox_DrawScrollBar(HWND hwnd)
{
    pLBStyle ls=ListBox_GetSettings(hwnd);
    if(!ls) return -1;
    
    RECT rc_mem,rc_vs,rc_thumb;
    
    if(ListBox_GetZoneRect(hwnd,ZVSCROLL,&rc_vs,TRUE)!=0) return -1;
    CopyRect(&rc_mem,&rc_vs);
    OffsetRect(&rc_mem,-rc_vs.left,-rc_vs.top);

    //initial gdi resource
    HDC hdc=GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    HDC memdc=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP bmp=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,rc_mem.right-rc_mem.left,rc_mem.bottom-rc_mem.top);
    HBITMAP pre_bmp=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc,bmp);
    
    //background of the scrollbar
    FillRect(memdc,&rc_mem,ls->brush);
    
    if(ListBox_GetZoneRect(hwnd,ZVSTHUMB,&rc_thumb,TRUE)!=0) return -1;
    OffsetRect(&rc_thumb,-rc_vs.left,-rc_vs.top);

    //thumb rect
    Graphics graphic(memdc);
    graphic.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeHighQuality);
    GraphicsPath path;
    LinearGradientBrush pbrush(Rect(rc_thumb.left,rc_thumb.top,SCROLLBAR_PIXLS,SCROLLBAR_PIXLS),
                              Color(255,10,10,10),Color(255,90,90,90),LinearGradientModeHorizontal);
    path.AddArc(rc_thumb.left,rc_thumb.top,SCROLLBAR_PIXLS,SCROLLBAR_PIXLS,180,180);
    path.AddArc(rc_thumb.left,rc_thumb.bottom-SCROLLBAR_PIXLS,SCROLLBAR_PIXLS,SCROLLBAR_PIXLS,0,180);
    graphic.FillPath(&pbrush,&path);
    
    //blt
    BitBlt(hdc,rc_vs.left,rc_vs.top,rc_vs.right-rc_vs.left,rc_vs.bottom-rc_vs.top,
           memdc,0,0,SRCCOPY);        
    
    //release gdi resource
    DeleteObject(SelectObject(memdc,pre_bmp));
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
    return 0;
}
```

3. `WM_NCHITTEST`: Recognize the scrollbar zone hit.
4. `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`: Recognize if the hit on the scrollbar zone, if is, determining it is a dragging action of thumb rect. Howerver, acccording some source code , people don't do this in `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` procedure, they usually do this in `WM_SETCURSOR`. I don't know why.
5. `WM_SETCURSOR`: If NC_HitTest was in scrollbar rect, and the WM_SETCURSOR was triggered by WM_NCLUBTTONDOWN, that means user trying to scroll the control, now user doing dragging actions.

```
    case WM_SETCURSOR: {
        UINT hit_pos=LOWORD(lParam);
        UINT trigger_msg=HIWORD(lParam);
        
        if(hit_pos!=HTVSCROLL) return CallWindowProc(ls->pre_proc,hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
        
        if(trigger_msg==WM_LBUTTONDOWN||trigger_msg==WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) {
            POINT pt={0};
            RECT rc;
            
            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            //ScreenToClient(hwnd,&pt);
            ListBox_GetZoneRect(hwnd,ZVSTHUMB,&rc,FALSE);
            
            if(PtInRect(&rc,pt)) {
                SetCapture(hwnd);
                ls->scroll_state=THUMB_VCLICK;
            }
        }
    } break;
```

**WHAT IS THE TROUBLE**

6. `WM_MOUSEMOVE`: Update the scrollbar info , repaint the scrollbar according the scrollinfo updated.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
    if(GetCapture()!=hwnd) break;
    if(ls->scroll_state!=THUMB_VCLICK) break;
    
    //...

} break;
```

However, I can't get any WM_MOUSEMOVE message when dragging the thumb rect. Why ?

**THE REST PART**

Those messages down below are irrelevant for the problem yet. But I will still write the purpose of each.

7. `WM_NCLBUTTONUP`/`WM_LBUTTONUP`: Release the capture of the control, and it is a signal for stopping thumb dragging action.
8. `WM_PAINT`: Repaint the scrollbar.

PS: I figured it out and record here.

> Why can't get any WM_MOUSEMOVE message when calling SetCapture for a ListBox control?
> There is a very tiny change for for my coding.

The problem is the handle of WM_SETCURSOR or WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN.

```
    case WM_SETCURSOR: {
        UINT hit_pos=LOWORD(lParam);
        UINT trigger_msg=HIWORD(lParam);

        if(hit_pos!=HTVSCROLL) return CallWindowProc(ls->pre_proc,hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);

        if(trigger_msg==WM_LBUTTONDOWN||trigger_msg==WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN) {
            POINT pt={0};
            RECT rc;

            GetCursorPos(&pt);
            //ScreenToClient(hwnd,&pt);
            ListBox_GetZoneRect(hwnd,ZVSTHUMB,&rc,FALSE);

            if(PtInRect(&rc,pt)) {
                SetCapture(hwnd);
                ls->scroll_state=THUMB_VCLICK;

                return 0;// here it is.
            }
        }
    } break;
```

When you `SetCapture(hwnd)` , you should return 0 and finish the message handle, if `break;` here , the default procedure of control will take over and ruin all you have done.

Everytime when I feel been trapped , it always turned out to be something too tiny to care. Hum, everytime.

Comment: Don't change state in `WM_SETCURSOR`. Just set the cursor. Do the state change in `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`.

Comment: @RaymondChen  You are right. It only works in `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` . I don't know why.
Besides, this tricks seem **DO NOT** work on WC_EDIT control. If I applied `WS_VSCROLL` on `WC_EDIT` control, the initial gui interface has a scrollbar by default, even if there is no content in the edit box. This is different from a `WC_LISTBOX ` control. Why is that ?